# Why does reactive stream subscriber is executed in current thread?

Tags: java, project-reactor

`subscribe` documentation states:

> Keep in mind that since the sequence can be asynchronous, this will
> immediately return control to the calling thread. This can give the
> impression the consumer is not invoked when executing in a main thread
> or a unit test for instance.

So why do I see every element printed out? It means that lambda is executed in the main thread

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ReactorMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
                .limitRequest(5)
                .skip(3)
                .subscribe(value -> {
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Value: " + value);
                })
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the generation of values does not contain any asynchronous element. So when you subscribe to the Flux, it will use the current thread to do as many thing it can do, until an asynchronous element makes it wait and use the thread for something else.

If to produce your elements you are for example calling a web service in an asynchronous way, you will receive values in an asynchronous way.

You can test it by making the sequence delayed:

```java
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
                    .limitRequest(5)
                    .skip(3)
                    .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                    .subscribe(value -> {
                        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
                    })
            ;
        }
```